# Selenium + Python не могу "нажать" на кнопку

Tags: python, selenium

Ребята, перечитал все доки и все что можно перепробовал.  Не жмется кнопка.

Есть сайт по [ссылке](https://www.torgi.gov.ru/lotSearch1.html;jsessionid=_78AGWSGMkMPvWl9ischcC3w9OdwRFAI1-ZqINqZ8RLYRf1VtMBk!-1927104539!-1149436043?bidKindId=13). Мне надо надо нажать на кнопку-"книжку" так чтобы вылезло меню.

Вот мой код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
    return driver

def city_selection(web_adress):
    driver.get(web_adress)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id("id19").click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Box or Button not found")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()

url = "https://www.torgi.gov.ru/lotSearch1.html;jsessionid=_78AGWSGMkMPvWl9ischcC3w9OdwRFAI1-ZqINqZ8RLYRf1VtMBk!-1927104539!-1149436043?bidKindId=13"

city_selection(url)
```

пишет:

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"id19"}

пробовал также

```
      driver.find_element_by_class("ss_sprite ss_book_open").click()
```

пишет: 
driver.find_element_by_class("ss_sprite ss_book_open").click()
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class'

пробовал Xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='id19']/img[contains(@class, 'ss_sprite ss_book_open')]/@src").click()
```

пишет:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@id='id19']/img[contains(@class,
>   'ss_sprite ss_book_open')]/@src"}   (Session info:
>   chrome=68.0.3440.84)

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что, нельзя драйвером обращаться по контенту элемента)))

В вашем xpath, который вы написали - `//a[@id='id19']/img[contains(@class, 'ss_sprite ss_book_open')]/@src` - есть указатель на контент элемента `@src`.

Драйвер не будет работать с таким xpath. Удалите его и всё заработает)))

```
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="id19"]/img[contains(@class, "ss_sprite ss_book_open")]').click()
```

Указатель на контент можно использовать в библиотеках по парсингу xml, там, в таком случае, вернётся содержимое этого указателя - `img/s.gif`. А драйвер работает сначала с элементом, а потом с его контентом через `get_attribute("src")`

Где-то в доках, вы этот момент упустили)))

Answer (score 1):

Я вот так ищу и кликаю

```
def find_me(br, val):
    """ ==== Находим и возвращаем элемент ==== """
    try:
        element = br.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, val)
        return element
    except: pass


async def inter_number(br, number):
    """ ==== Вводим номер телефона и нажимаем кнопки ==== """
    log_code = find_me(br, ".login_phone_code_input_group > .md-input")
    log_code.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE * 3)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    log_code.send_keys('976')
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    str_num = str(number[2])[3:]
    log_code.send_keys(Keys.TAB + str_num)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    br.save_screenshot("screen.png")
    # Кликаем next
    find_me(br, "my-i18n").click()
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    # Кликаем ок
    find_me(br, ".btn-md-primary > span").click()
    await check_open(br, req_id = number[1])
```

Comment: Я ненашел книжку эту на сайте. Так бы прислал готовый варик

Comment: driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, #id18 > img).click()

Comment: Вот верхняя книжка